# How to deal with xml file in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am trying to convert an xml file into json before create a response to return it to user.

I am getting this error message:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Can someone point me out the right direction and tell me how to set this loader in next config if that's what needs to be done, please?

```
import xml2js from 'xml2js'
import {listing} from '../../listing.xml'


let parser = new  xml2js.Parser()
const data = () =>  parser.parseString(listing, function (err,result) {
  return result
}) 
console.log(data)
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data,null, 2))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using API Route, these will be handled on the server-side, which means you are able to use Node APIs to read files and parse with xml2js lib

```
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

export default (req, res) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), 'note.xml'));
  parseString(data, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  });
};
```

https://nextjs-gkkygf--3000.local.webcontainer.io/api/xml

[Full Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-gkkygf?file=pages/api/xml.js)